# Реализация записи и удаления строк в текстовый файл (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, файлы, циклы, telegram-bot, telebot

Решил сделать хранение id пользователей в отдельном файле, для последующего сравнения. Но запутался с алгоритмами записи и удаления.

```py
def handle_text(message):
    if message.text == 'subscribe':
        user_id = str(message.from_user.id)
        with open("users_id.txt", 'r+') as file:
            read = file.readlines()
            for line in read:
                if user_id in line:
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "u have been already subsribe")
                    keyboard.unsubsribe(message)
                else:
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "any text")
                    keyboard.subsribe(message)

def handle_text(message):
    if message.text == "unsubsrcibe":
            user_id = str(message.from_user.id)
            with open("users_id.txt", "r") as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
            with open("users_id.txt", "w") as f:
                for line in lines:
                    if line.strip("\n") == user_id:
                        f.write(line)
                        break
            keyboard.unsubscribe(message)
```

Помогите написать цикл который будет проверять находится ли id пользователя в текстовом файле, если да то бот меняет клавиатуру на ту, в которой кнопки подписки заменяется на кнопку отписки.

Comment: Просто вопрос, без критики: почему бы не использовать БД? Хотя бы SQLite

Comment: не думаю что наберётся большое число пользователей, следовательно нет необходимости в БД.

Comment: SQLite и не рассчитан на действительно большое число пользователей. Использование БД в разы упрощает поиск данных и повышает эффективность их хранения.

Comment: Хорошо, тогда попробую реализовать хранение в БД. Спасибо)

Comment: Стоит ли вынести это в качестве ответа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если еще не поздно.

```
def handle_text(message=None):
    #if message.text == 'subscribe':
    #user_id = str(message.from_user.id)
    user_id = 2 
    with open("E:\\Python\\exampeles\\users_id.txt", 'r') as file:
        #Получаем список айдишников пользователей file.readlines()
        #Убираем \n и переводим в числа
        users_id = [int(v.strip('\n')) for v in file.readlines()] 
        if user_id in users_id :
            print('YES')
            #bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "u have been already subsribe")
            #keyboard.unsubsribe(message)
        elif user_id not in users_id :
            print('NO')
            #bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "any text")
            #keyboard.subsribe(message)



handle_text()
```